# Excel: search multiple strings then return value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using the following formula to search for a string and return a value

```
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CHA*",B:B),"CINEMA","")
```

If I want to search for multiple strings whats the formula?, I've tried the following but it isn't returning anything

```
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"odeon*","vue*"},B:B),"CINEMA","")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"odeon*","vue*"},B:B))>0,"CINEMA","")
```

Another way:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"odeon*","vue*"},B:B))),"CINEMA","")
```

Use `AND()` if you require ALL substrings to match:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"odeon*","vue*"},B:B))),"CINEMA","")
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you're missing a `)` on either formula. And for them to work anyway, you should, as Taosique pointed out, use `=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(` if you need just one substring, or `=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(` if you require both.

Good luck!